# How can I see any tar progress when I use `--xform`

Tags: tar

I have following function in order to extract discarding directory structure.

```bsh
tarx() {
    STRIP=${1%.*}  # strip last suffix
    NAME=${STRIP%.tar}  # strip .tar suffix, if present
    tar -xvf "$1" --xform="s|^|$NAME/|S"
}

$ tarx bone.n26c100.tbz2
```

Here I want to see progress bar while extracting.

I have tried:

```bsh
$ pv "$1" | tar -xvf "$1" --xform="s|^|$NAME/|S"
B 0:00:29 [0.00 B/s] [<=>
```

which does not show the progress change. How can I apply progress bar if `tar` is using `--xform=` flag.

---

Related: https://superuser.com/questions/168749/is-there-a-way-to-see-any-tar-progress-per-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `tar` to read from the pipe, not the file:

```
pv "$1" | tar -xvf - --xform="s|^|$NAME/|S"
```

Comment: I have to add `-j` flag due to `tar: Archive is compressed. Use -j option` error message

Comment: Ah, so you need `tar -xjvf - ...`.